# calculating mean for consecutive numbers two by two in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a dataset in which for every year, I have some data in columns based on specific years.

```
    result_birth <- tibble::tibble( "1970" =c(8.816455, 21.41139,39.0443,51.639236, 59.196197,      100.759485, 76.829107,103.278472,79.348094,99.499991, 81.867081, 78.088601), 
                      "1971"=  c(18.878066 ,30.204906 ,42.790284 ,65.443964 ,69.219577 ,80.546417   ,114.526936 ,94.390332 ,108.234248 ,83.063492 ,103.200096 ,72.99519 ), 
                      "1972"=  c(8.801375 ,22.632107 ,36.462839 ,56.580268 ,69.153661 ,76.697696 ,80.469714 ,109.388518 ,96.815125 ,108.131179 ,69.153661 ,91.785768 ), 
                      "1973"= c(14.675905 ,20.790865 ,31.797794 ,64.818581 ,58.70362 ,86.832438 ,85.609446 ,96.616375 ,97.839367 ,78.271493 ,105.177319 ,53.811652 ))
```

I want to have the mean of data two by two, from the bottom of the data frame. the last rwos must be the same as the original dataset. For instance, for the first row, we will have something like this:

[image: old and new data]

I wrote some codes to do this but this code has two problems: First, it starts from above; therefore, the first row must be the same as old data,(I want the opposite, and the last row to be the same as the old row). Second, these codes are very cumbersome, I need something more user-friendly.

```
nrows <- nrow(result_birth)

total_birth <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrows, ncol = 
ncol(result_birth)))

for (i in 1:ncol(result_birth)) {
    for (j in 2:nrows) {
        total_birth[j, i]<-(result_birth[j,i]+result_birth[j-1,i])/2
    }
}
```

Comment: For the new dataset, I don't need the old data and the new data must fill the old data place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `dplyr::lead()` and the `.names` argument in `dplyr::mutate`. Typically your function could just be `~(.x + lead(.x)) / 2)` but that will leave an `NA` in the last row - since you want the last row to be equivalent to the original value in the row,  a quick workaround is to nest an `if_else` statement in there to test if there is an `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)

result_birth %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~(.x + if_else(!is.na(lead(.x)), lead(.x), .x)) / 2, 
                .names = "mean_{col}"))
```

Output:

```
#    `1970` `1971` `1972` `1973` mean_1970 mean_1971 mean_1972 mean_1973
# <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1   8.82   18.9   8.80    14.7      15.1      24.5      15.7      17.7
# 2   21.4    30.2  22.6    20.8      30.2      36.5      29.5      26.3
# 3   39.0    42.8  36.5    31.8      45.3      54.1      46.5      48.3
# 4   51.6    65.4  56.6    64.8      55.4      67.3      62.9      61.8
# 5   59.2    69.2  69.2    58.7      80.0      74.9      72.9      72.8
# 6   101.    80.5  76.7    86.8      88.8      97.5      78.6      86.2
# 7   76.8    115.  80.5    85.6      90.1      104.      94.9      91.1
# 8   103.    94.4  109.    96.6      91.3      101.      103.      97.2
# 9   79.3    108.  96.8    97.8      89.4      95.6      102.      88.1
# 10  99.5    83.1  108.    78.3      90.7      93.1      88.6      91.7
# 11  81.9    103.  69.2    105.      80.0      88.1      80.5      79.5
# 12  78.1    73.0  91.8    53.8      78.1      73.0      91.8      53.8
```

If you just want to replace the original columns with the means (not create new columns), just drop the `.names` argument:

```
result_birth %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~(.x + if_else(!is.na(lead(.x)), lead(.x), .x)) / 2))
```

Comment: Dear @jpsmith, if I want the process to start from the bottom of the data frame and the first row to be the same as old data, which part of the code must be altered?

Comment: @AzamMirzaei - change both instances of `lead(...)` to `lag(...)`

Comment: Dear @jpsmith, how can use lead(...) and lag(...) function, to calculate something like this:
x is a number in a column:       (x+(x+1)*2+(x+3)*2+(x+4)*2+x+5)/8

Comment: sample<-sample %>%
  mutate(prob = (x + 2 * lead(x) + 2 * lead(x, 2) + 
                   2 * lead(x, 3) + lead(x, 4))/8) %>%
  as.data.frame()

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `zoo`. Edited for new requirements:

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)
result_birth2 <- result_birth %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                .fns = ~rollapply(.x, 2,mean,
                                  align = 'right', partial = T)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# `1970` `1971` `1972` `1973`
# <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#   1   8.82   18.9   8.80   14.7
# 2  15.1    24.5  15.7    17.7
# 3  30.2    36.5  29.5    26.3
# 4  45.3    54.1  46.5    48.3
# 5  55.4    67.3  62.9    61.8
# 6  80.0    74.9  72.9    72.8
# 7  88.8    97.5  78.6    86.2
# 8  90.1   104.   94.9    91.1
# 9  91.3   101.  103.     97.2
# 10  89.4    95.6 102.     88.1
# 11  90.7    93.1  88.6    91.7
# 12  80.0    88.1  80.5    79.5
```

Comment: Is it possible to omit the old data so that we can just have new data with the same column name?

Comment: Yes, if you don't use the `.names` argument, they'll be replaced automatically

Comment: Dear @JuanC, if I want the process to start from the bottom of the data frame and the first row to be the same as old data, which part of the code must be altered?

Comment: change left for right in the code (:

Comment: Dear @JuanC,  how can use the lead(...) and lag(...) functions, to calculate something like this in my dataset:
 x is a number in a column: 
(x+(x+1)*2+(x+3)*2+(x+4)*2+x+5)/8 
until the end of the column which is more than thousand observation.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

result_birth <- tibble::tibble( "1970" =c(8.816455, 21.41139,39.0443,51.639236, 59.196197,      100.759485, 76.829107,103.278472,79.348094,99.499991, 81.867081, 78.088601), 
                                "1971"=  c(18.878066 ,30.204906 ,42.790284 ,65.443964 ,69.219577 ,80.546417   ,114.526936 ,94.390332 ,108.234248 ,83.063492 ,103.200096 ,72.99519 ), 
                                "1972"=  c(8.801375 ,22.632107 ,36.462839 ,56.580268 ,69.153661 ,76.697696 ,80.469714 ,109.388518 ,96.815125 ,108.131179 ,69.153661 ,91.785768 ), 
                                "1973"= c(14.675905 ,20.790865 ,31.797794 ,64.818581 ,58.70362 ,86.832438 ,85.609446 ,96.616375 ,97.839367 ,78.271493 ,105.177319 ,53.811652 ))




ave2_birth <- map_dfc(
  result_birth,
  \(x) rev(slide_dbl(.x = rev(x),
                 .f = mean,
                 .before = 1,
                 .complete = FALSE))
)

result_birth
ave2_birth
```